# A form may include HTML attributes such as maxlength

Tags: django, django-forms

Django 1.10.

The documentation reads:
"Just like when using a normal Form, each form in the formset may include HTML attributes such as maxlength for browser validation." (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#formset-validation)

```
class ArticleForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=5)
```

Which results in:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="id_form-0-title">Title:</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input id="id_form-0-title" maxlength="5" name="form-0-title" type="text" value="Test" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Keywords: **form** may include HTML attributes such as maxlength.

What astonishes me: this is not the form that may include maxlength. This is a field in Django and input tag in HTML. Well, a form can contain maxlength neither in Django nor in HTML as far as I know.

Could you help me understand: is it correct to say that a form may include maxlength attribute? Is it a bad wording in the documentation? Or maybe a form really can contain such attributes.

Comment: A form input can have a maxlength...http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Comment: Keyword is input, isn't it? Input tag can. A form itself can't. That is the essence of question.

Comment: Yes, the documentation could be improved here: it's talking about form fields or form inputs, not forms as a whole.